# Compare number of foreign keys from each id, with another database

Tags: mysql, sql

There's two databases with identical structure.
Inside each db there's these two tables.

**- Table 'Client'**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | name            | document        |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
```

---

**- Table 'Purchases'**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | id_client       | product         |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
```

---

I would like to know how to insert into a third database(db3), all the clients that are equal in db1 and db2, and that have the same number of foreign keys related to them.
Logically would be something like:
Insert into db3.clients, equal clients rows from db1.clients and db2.clients where count(db1.Purchases.id_client) = count(db2.Purchases.id_client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set of JOINs to select

1. clients in both db1 and db2
2. the # of purchases for each client in db1
3. the clients in db2 that have the same # of purchases

Then, you can simply use the INSERT statement to insert these selected rows, as below:

```
INSERT INTO db3.clients
SELECT c1.*
FROM db1.clients c1
INNER JOIN db2.clients c2
ON c1.id = c2.id
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        id_client,
        count(*) cnt_purchases
    FROM db1.Purchases
    GROUP BY id_client
) p1
ON c1.id = p1.id_client
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        id_client,
        count(*) cnt_purchases
    FROM db2.Purchases
    GROUP BY id_client
) p2
ON p1.id_client = p2.id_client AND p1.cnt_purchases = p2.cnt_purchases;
```

Comment: Joseph B, What if ids for same clients are diffents on both dbs? Like client Johnny has ID 3 on db1 but id 6 on db2.

Comment: In that case, you would end up with two rows with different id's but the same name in db3. If you want to compare using the name, then if you find a match between db1 and db2, you need to know which id to insert into db3.